# Is it good to buy iPhone Se for App Development?

Tags: iphone

I m planning to purchase iPhone device for iOS development. And my pocket budget is too less... :(. So if i purchase iPhone SE, then is it work for me. Like, can app developed on iPhone SE will run perfectly on iPhone 6, 6s, 7 etc.

I m really confused so please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can app developed on iPhone SE will run perfectly on iPhone 6, 6s, 7

Testing whether your interface is laid out correctly on different screen sizes can be done using the Simulator. However, it's best to test also on a device, as a device can do things the Simulator cannot do, and things like memory and speed and energy usage can only be tested on a device.

Most developers have just one device, or perhaps two, an iPhone and an iPad. You should get a device with any features you intend to use in your app and that cannot be tested in the Simulator; for example, if you're going to use 3D touch, or the barometer, an iPhone SE isn't going to do you any good, because it lacks those features.  But if you're willing to exclude features you cannot test, you should be fine with an SE.